# Django ModelForm - Using ForeignKey for Choices

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm attempting to build out a rather large "Patient Onboarding" form using ModelForms.

I'm having trouble getting the choices within the foreign keys to appear in the admin area or to the rendered form without manually adding them to the Postgres database.

There has got to be a more efficient way to be doing this...thanks in advance!

```
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms

class Patient(models.Model):
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='First Name', blank=False)
     middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Middle Name', blank=False)
     last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Last Name', blank=False)
     gender = models.ForeignKey('GenderChoices', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Gender', blank=False)
     date_of_birth = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date of Birth', blank=False)
     medications = models.ForeignKey('MedicationsYesNo', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Do you currently take any medications?', blank=False)

class MedicationsYesNo(models.Model):
    medications_yes_no = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        choices = [
            ('Yes', 'Yes'),
            ('No', 'No')
        ]
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.medications_yes_no

class OnboardingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Why don't you remove `MedicationsYesNo`? I mean you can define `medications_yes_no` inside `Patient`, instead of having `ForeignKey`.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. I was making it too complex...